# Rank labels of features by size with an expression in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, expression

There is a layer ne_10m_geography_marine_polys with labels for various maritime features. Of course, features are different by size (oceans and straits, for example), so it needed to be different sizes of labels fonts. Actually, it can be done manually, but take lots of time.
There is a field "scalerank" with valuations from '0' (largest) to '9' (smallest).
So I wonder, maybe it can be some expressions that can be used to set the sizes of labels fonts using this field?

Comment: Well, what have you tried? Have you defined which scalerank corresponds to which size? Have you read up on data-defined override?

Comment: I'm tried this, but it not works:                                                                                                                   WHEN  "scalerank"  = '0' THEN 48
    WHEN "scalerank" = '1' THEN 20
    WHEN "scalerank" = '2' THEN 18
 WHEN "scalerank" = '3' THEN 16
 WHEN "scalerank" = '4' THEN 14
 WHEN "scalerank" = '5' THEN 12
 WHEN "scalerank" = '6' THEN 10
 WHEN "scalerank" = '7' THEN 8
 WHEN "scalerank" = '8' THEN 8
 WHEN "scalerank" = '9' THEN 6
END

Comment: Actually, I did. It just slipped when I copied it to this site. It's not worked with:                                                                                                     CASE
    WHEN "scalerank" = '0' THEN 48
    WHEN "scalerank" = '1' THEN 20
    WHEN "scalerank" = '2' THEN 18
    WHEN "scalerank" = '3' THEN 16
    WHEN "scalerank" = '4' THEN 14
    WHEN "scalerank" = '5' THEN 12
    WHEN "scalerank" = '6' THEN 10
    WHEN "scalerank" IN ('7', '8') THEN 8
    WHEN "scalerank" = '9' THEN 6
END

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As defined [in the `CASE` function documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html?#case) :

> CASE
> WHEN condition THEN result
> [ …n ]
> [ ELSE result ]
> END
>
> [ ] marks optional components

The expression for the label size function of the `"scalerank"` field is :

```sql
CASE
    WHEN "scalerank" = '0' THEN 48
    WHEN "scalerank" = '1' THEN 20
    WHEN "scalerank" = '2' THEN 18
    WHEN "scalerank" = '3' THEN 16
    WHEN "scalerank" = '4' THEN 14
    WHEN "scalerank" = '5' THEN 12
    WHEN "scalerank" = '6' THEN 10
    WHEN "scalerank" IN ('7', '8') THEN 8
    WHEN "scalerank" = '9' THEN 6
END
```

Result :

[image: result of different label size in QGIS]

Comment: No, this is not  work

Comment: @GeoEth: I added a screenshot of the result, with a simple point layer and a field `"scalerank"` (string) filled with values from `'0'` to `'9'`.

Comment: @GeoEth If the scalerank field is a text field the syntax is '9' (single quote around value) if scalerank is a numeric field the syntax become 9 (value without any quote)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just figured it out. The solution above that I marked as accepted answer works, but only if you don't touch this button (in red circle):
[image]

In previous attempts, I tried to set some values with this button. Thanks for the answer!